# How to stop the layer being removed from the map window after packing the table

Tags: mapinfo

In MapInfo whenever I pack a table that's open in the map window, it closes it in the map window and I have to reopen it. How can I prevent this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. Before you pack the table, save a 'whatever working' workspace to keep your layer structure and style overrides etc intact. Pack the table and reopen the 'working workspace'.

Answer (score 1):

In the later versions of MapInfo Pro, the process that Ross describes has been automated.

The Advanced Pack tool will save a workspace before packing your table(s) and then open that workspace again once the table(s) have been packed.

And yes, you can also pack multiple tables in one process.